# Help needed to choose the right version of ubuntu to install

Tags: installation, laptop, version

I have planned to buy a laptop that comes with Free DOS. My question's are:

1. Will ubuntu work on laptop's? if so
2. Can i install ubuntu that is there for download i.e., ubuntu 11.10/ ubuntu10.04 LTS.
3. And second question is which version 32/64-bit should i download.

here is that link for the laptop that i have planned to buy:

http://www.flipkart.com/computers/laptops/hp/itmdywe3t8zpzhxm?pid=comdywd8ssbsxk9y

Please fell free to answer my query i'm a novice at these things.

Comment: 1.It should//2.All Ubuntu ISOs are for download.. I don't know what you mean by that, If you're asking whether one version will work than the Other, then t's up to you which one to choose///3.64, no need to have 32 on this new Laptop.

Comment: Hi buddy thanks for the help. Waiting for my laptop eagerly........

Comment: for the Second Question i mean to say should i go for 11.10 or 10.04 !!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the system requirements for each flavour of Ubuntu Desktop](http://askubuntu.com/q/333795), [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](http://askubuntu.com/q/206407) ([see also *this*](http://askubuntu.com/q/690)), or [What are the differences between 32-bit and 64-bit, and which should I choose?](http://askubuntu.com/q/7034) ([see also *that*](http://askubuntu.com/q/54296))

Answer (score 1):

1. I recommend Ubuntu 11.10 because it is the newest version, and in 3 months the 12.04 LTS will be out. So in this way you get familiar with the new feature until the long time support (12.04 LTS) will be out.
2. If your laptop is 64 bit architecture, definitely go and install the 64bit Ubuntu

P.S. I looked over your laptop, and it can handle 64 bit. go for it.

Comment: Thank a lot Mr/Ms.bioShark recommendations accepted. Will definitly wait for 12.04LTS to be released in a couple of months.

Answer (score 1):

1. yes
2. yes
3. 64 Bit because its recommended & you have 4 GB of RAM

Comment: Hey Mr/Ms.PizzaPill thank you very much for the answers. Indeed you helped me a lot and me being breakdown on this subject from a few days.

Comment: you are very welcome

Answer (score 0):

I think Your first question is too general. Some hardware causes issues when working under Linux (mostly because of drivers problems). If I may suggest something, please see [Ubuntu certification website](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/). There You can find descriptions of issues (if any) and given workarounds to them. Choose one that is described as least problematic for Ubuntu. That is how I would make a choice if PC is not bought already.
The second thing is, that a lot of hardware producers don't care about (quite large) Linux users community. So if You have chosen some equipment, see what it has inside, and check if producers offer drivers for linux on ther websites or on the CDs/DVDs that come with it. This way You will not only avoid problems with drivers, but also support Linux community by choosing Linux friendly producer.
And personally I would suggest laptop with nVidia VGA card, but that is my personal suggestion.

As for second question: of course You can install Ubuntu

Your processor is 64 bit so You should choose 64bit OS.

Regards

Comment: hi buddy the certification website was hell-lot of help for me!!!!

Comment: Glad to help You :]

Answer (score 0):

Probably not what you want to hear, but I would wait for 12.04 LTS to hit stable if you're new to ubuntu.  That way you don't either

a)install an old LTS that's about to go end of support
b)install a new intermediate only to reinstall 12.04 in a couple months
c)install 11.10 only to reinstall 12.04 or go through an upgrade process

I can just see installing 11.10 and then wanting to keep all settings and not liking some weirdness that can happen during the dist-upgrade process.