# How to remove GNOME completely?

Tags: gnome

I want make my installed Ubuntu as light as possible to launch only on 256MB RAM machine (VirtualBox)?

So I'm thinking about removing GNOME and related components completely. How can I do that?

This link does not help me:
http://complete-concrete-concise.com/ubuntu-2/ubuntu-12-04/ubuntu-12-04-how-to-completely-uninstall-remove-gnome

Comment: By default, Gnome is not included in Ubuntu 12.04. Unity can be removed according to [these instructions](http://blogs.operationaldynamics.com/paul/opensource/not-unified-removing-unity-from-ubuntu-12-04-lts#the-actual-juice). If you want no WM, X can be removed recursively (removing everything that depends on it) by purging xserver-xorg. GNOME, if you have installed it via the gnome3 PPA, can be removed like [this](http://supportlife.wordpress.com/2011/05/31/tutorial-how-to-removeuninstall-gnome-3-in-ubuntu-11-04-natty-narwhal/).

Answer (score 8):

After installing Ubuntu 12.10 desktop edition, here's how you remove Unity, X11 and any graphical applications that come installed by default:

- Log out, and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd> to enter the first virtual terminal, leaving X's graphical environment. If you're using VirtualBox and are in a virtual machine, press <kbd>Right Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd> instead.
- Enter your username and password.
- Run this command to remove Unity:

  ```
  sudo apt-get remove unity \
  unity-asset-pool \
  unity-services \
  'unity-lens-.*' \
  'unity-scope-.*' \
  'liboverlay-scrollbar.*' \
  appmenu-gtk  \
  appmenu-gtk3  \
  appmenu-qt \
  firefox-globalmenu \
  thunderbird-globalmenu \
  unity-common \
  'libunity.*' \
  unity-greeter \
  'unity-webapps-.*' \
  'indicator-.*' \
  xul-ext-unity
  ```
- Run this command to remove X, graphical programs and anything else that you
  wouldn't expect on a server. This list was generated by comparing the list of
  installed packages on a freshly installed Ubuntu 12.10 desktop system, and a
  freshly installed Ubuntu 12.10 server system.

  ```
  sudo apt-get remove \
  account-plugin-aim \
  account-plugin-facebook \
  account-plugin-flickr \
  account-plugin-google \
  account-plugin-icons \
  account-plugin-identica \
  account-plugin-jabber \
  account-plugin-salut \
  account-plugin-twitter \
  account-plugin-windows-live \
  account-plugin-yahoo \
  acl \
  acpi-support \
  activity-log-manager-common \
  activity-log-manager-control-center \
  adium-theme-ubuntu \
  aisleriot \
  alsa-base \
  alsa-utils \
  anacron \
  apg \
  app-install-data \
  app-install-data-partner \
  apport-gtk \
  aptdaemon-data \
  aptdaemon \
  apturl-common \
  apturl \
  aspell-en \
  aspell \
  at-spi2-core \
  avahi-autoipd \
  avahi-daemon \
  avahi-utils \
  bamfdaemon \
  baobab \
  bluez-alsa \
  bluez-cups \
  bluez-gstreamer \
  bluez \
  branding-ubuntu \
  brasero-cdrkit \
  brasero-common \
  brasero \
  brltty \
  checkbox \
  checkbox-qt \
  colord \
  compiz-core \
  compiz-gnome \
  compiz \
  compiz-plugins-default \
  cracklib-runtime \
  cryptsetup-bin \
  cups-bsd \
  cups-client \
  cups-common \
  cups-filters \
  cups \
  cups-ppdc \
  dbus-x11 \
  dc \
  dconf-gsettings-backend \
  dconf-service \
  dconf-tools \
  deja-dup \
  desktop-file-utils \
  dictionaries-common \
  diffstat \
  dmz-cursor-theme \
  dnsmasq-base \
  doc-base \
  duplicity \
  dvd+rw-tools \
  empathy-common \
  empathy \
  enchant \
  eog \
  espeak-data \
  evince-common \
  evince \
  evolution-data-server-common \
  evolution-data-server \
  example-content \
  file-roller \
  firefox-gnome-support \
  firefox \
  firefox-locale-en \
  folks-common \
  fontconfig-config \
  fontconfig \
  fonts-freefont-ttf \
  fonts-kacst \
  fonts-kacst-one \
  fonts-khmeros-core \
  fonts-lao \
  fonts-liberation \
  fonts-lklug-sinhala \
  fonts-nanum \
  fonts-opensymbol \
  fonts-sil-abyssinica \
  fonts-sil-padauk \
  fonts-takao-pgothic \
  fonts-thai-tlwg \
  fonts-tibetan-machine \
  fonts-tlwg-garuda \
  fonts-tlwg-kinnari \
  fonts-tlwg-loma \
  fonts-tlwg-mono \
  fonts-tlwg-norasi \
  fonts-tlwg-purisa \
  fonts-tlwg-sawasdee \
  fonts-tlwg-typewriter \
  fonts-tlwg-typist \
  fonts-tlwg-typo \
  fonts-tlwg-umpush \
  fonts-tlwg-waree \
  foomatic-db-compressed-ppds \
  foomatic-db-engine \
  foomatic-filters \
  freerdp-x11 \
  gcalctool \
  gconf2-common \
  gconf2 \
  gconf-service-backend \
  gconf-service \
  gcr \
  gdb \
  gedit-common \
  gedit \
  genisoimage \
  geoclue \
  geoclue-ubuntu-geoip \
  gettext \
  ghostscript-cups \
  ghostscript \
  ghostscript-x \
  gir1.2-accounts-1.0 gir1.2-appindicator3-0.1 gir1.2-atk-1.0 gir1.2-atspi-2.0 gir1.2-dbusmenu-glib-0.4 gir1.2-dee-1.0 gir1.2-freedesktop gir1.2-gdata-0.0 gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0 gir1.2-gmenu-3.0 gir1.2-gnomebluetooth-1.0 gir1.2-gnomekeyring-1.0 gir1.2-goa-1.0 gir1.2-gst-plugins-base-0.10 gir1.2-gstreamer-0.10 gir1.2-gtk-3.0 gir1.2-gtksource-3.0 gir1.2-gudev-1.0 gir1.2-indicate-0.7 gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-3.0 gir1.2-messagingmenu-1.0 gir1.2-notify-0.7 gir1.2-pango-1.0 gir1.2-peas-1.0 gir1.2-rb-3.0 gir1.2-signon-1.0 gir1.2-soup-2.4 gir1.2-syncmenu-0.1 gir1.2-totem-1.0 gir1.2-totem-plparser-1.0 gir1.2-ubuntuoneui-3.0 gir1.2-unity-5.0 gir1.2-vte-2.90 gir1.2-webkit-3.0 gir1.2-wnck-3.0 \
  gksu \
  glib-networking-common \
  glib-networking \
  glib-networking-services \
  gnome-accessibility-themes gnome-bluetooth gnome-contacts gnome-control-center-data gnome-control-center gnome-control-center-signon gnome-desktop3-data gnome-disk-utility gnome-font-viewer gnome-games-data gnome-icon-theme gnome-icon-theme-symbolic gnome-keyring gnome-mahjongg gnome-media gnome-menus gnome-online-accounts gnome-orca gnome-power-manager gnome-screensaver gnome-screenshot gnome-session-bin gnome-session-canberra gnome-session-common gnome-session gnome-settings-daemon gnome-sudoku gnome-system-log gnome-system-monitor gnome-terminal-data gnome-terminal gnome-user-guide gnome-user-share \
  gnomine \
  growisofs \
  gsettings-desktop-schemas \
  gsfonts \
  gstreamer0.10-alsa \
  gstreamer0.10-gconf \
  gstreamer0.10-nice \
  gstreamer0.10-plugins-base-apps \
  gstreamer0.10-plugins-base \
  gstreamer0.10-plugins-good \
  gstreamer0.10-pulseaudio \
  gstreamer0.10-tools \
  gstreamer0.10-x \
  gtk2-engines \
  gtk2-engines-murrine \
  gtk3-engines-unico \
  gucharmap \
  guile-1.8-libs \
  gvfs-backends \
  gvfs-bin \
  gvfs-common \
  gvfs-daemons \
  gvfs-fuse \
  gvfs \
  gvfs-libs \
  gwibber \
  gwibber-service-facebook \
  gwibber-service-identica \
  gwibber-service \
  gwibber-service-twitter \
  hardening-includes \
  hicolor-icon-theme \
  hpijs \
  hplip-data \
  hplip \
  humanity-icon-theme \
  hunspell-en-us \
  hwdata \
  ibus-gtk3 \
  ibus-gtk \
  ibus \
  ibus-pinyin-db-android \
  ibus-pinyin \
  ibus-table \
  im-switch \
  indicator-appmenu \
  indicator-datetime \
  indicator-printers \
  inputattach \
  intel-gpu-tools \
  intltool-debian \
  iputils-arping \
  iw \
  kerneloops-daemon \
  landscape-client-ui-install \
  language-pack-en-base \
  language-pack-en \
  language-pack-gnome-en-base \
  language-pack-gnome-en \
  language-selector-gnome \
  libaa1 libaccount-plugin-1.0-0 libaccounts-glib0 libaccounts-qt1 libappindicator1 libappindicator3-1 libapt-pkg-perl libarchive12 libarchive-zip-perl libart-2.0-2 libasound2 libasound2-plugins libaspell15 libasyncns0 libatasmart4 libatk1.0-0 libatk1.0-data libatk-adaptor-data libatk-adaptor libatk-bridge2.0-0 libatkmm-1.6-1 libatspi2.0-0 libaudio2 libavahi-client3 libavahi-common3 libavahi-common-data libavahi-core7 libavahi-glib1 libavahi-gobject0 libavc1394-0 libbamf3-0 libbluetooth3 libboost-date-time1.49.0 libbrasero-media3-1 libbrlapi0.5 libburn4 libcaca0 libcairo2 libcairo-gobject2 libcairomm-1.0-1 libcairo-perl libcamel-1.2-40 libcanberra0 libcanberra-gtk0 libcanberra-gtk3-0 libcanberra-gtk3-module libcanberra-gtk-module libcanberra-pulse libcap2-bin libcap2 libcdio13 libcdio-cdda1 libcdio-paranoia1 libcdparanoia0 libclone-perl libclutter-1.0-0 libclutter-1.0-common libclutter-gst-1.0-0 libclutter-gtk-1.0-0 libcmis-0.2-2 libcogl9 libcogl-common libcogl-pango0 libcolord1 libcompizconfig0 libcrack2 libcroco3 libcrypt-passwdmd5-perl libcryptsetup4 libcups2 libcupscgi1 libcupsfilters1 libcupsimage2 libcupsmime1 libcupsppdc1 libcurl3-nss libdaemon0 libdatrie1 libdbusmenu-glib4 libdbusmenu-gtk3-4 libdbusmenu-gtk4 libdbusmenu-qt2 libdconf1 libdecoration0 libdee-1.0-4 libdevmapper-event1.02.1 libdigest-hmac-perl libdiscid0 libdjvulibre21 libdjvulibre-text libdmapsharing-3.0-2 libdotconf1.0 libdrm-nouveau2 libdv4 libebackend-1.2-5 libebook-1.2-14 libecal-1.2-15 libedata-book-1.2-15 libedata-cal-1.2-18 libedataserver-1.2-17 libemail-valid-perl libenchant1c2a libespeak1 libevdocument3-4 libevview3-3 libexempi3 libexif12 libexiv2-12 libexttextcat-1.0-0 libexttextcat-data libfarstream-0.1-0 libfile-basedir-perl libfile-copy-recursive-perl libfile-desktopentry-perl libfile-mimeinfo-perl libflac8 libfolks25 libfolks-eds25 libfolks-telepathy25 libfontconfig1 libfontembed1 libfontenc1 libframe6 libfreerdp1 libfreerdp-plugins-standard libfs6 libgail18 libgail-3-0 libgail-common libgck-1-0 libgconf-2-4 libgcr-3-1 libgcr-3-common libgd2-xpm libgdata13 libgdata-common libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common libgee2 libgeis1 libgeoclue0 libgettextpo0 libgexiv2-1 libgksu2-0 libgl1-mesa-dri libgl1-mesa-glx libglapi-mesa libglew1.8 libglewmx1.8 libglib2.0-bin libglib2.0-data libglibmm-2.4-1c2a libglib-perl libglu1-mesa libgmime-2.6-0 libgnome-bluetooth11 libgnome-control-center1 libgnome-desktop-3-4 libgnomekbd8 libgnomekbd-common libgnome-keyring0 libgnome-keyring-common libgnome-media-profiles-3.0-0 libgnome-menu2 libgnome-menu-3-0 libgoa-1.0-0 libgoa-1.0-common libgpgme11 libgphoto2-2 libgphoto2-l10n libgphoto2-port0 libgpod4 libgpod-common libgrail5 libgrip0 libgs9-common libgs9 libgssdp-1.0-3 libgstreamer0.10-0 libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0 libgtk2.0-0 libgtk2.0-bin libgtk2.0-common libgtk2-perl libgtk-3-0 libgtk-3-bin libgtk-3-common libgtkmm-2.4-1c2a libgtkmm-3.0-1 libgtksourceview-3.0-0 libgtksourceview-3.0-common libgtkspell-3-0 libgtop2-7 libgtop2-common libgucharmap-2-90-7 libgudev-1.0-0 libgupnp-1.0-4 libgupnp-igd-1.0-4 libgusb2 libgutenprint2 libgweather-3-1 libgweather-common libgwibber3 libgwibber-gtk3 libgxps2 libhpmud0 libhunspell-1.3-0 libhyphen0 libibus-1.0-0 libical0 libice6 libicu48 libido3-0.1-0 libiec61883-0 libieee1284-3 libijs-0.35 libimobiledevice3 libindicate5 libindicator3-7 libindicator7 libio-pty-perl libio-socket-inet6-perl libipc-run-perl libisofs6 libjack-jackd2-0 libjasper1 libjavascriptcoregtk-3.0-0 libjbig0 libjbig2dec0 libjpeg8 libjpeg-turbo8 libjs-jquery libjson0 libjson-glib-1.0-0 libjte1 libkpathsea6 liblcms1 liblcms2-2 liblightdm-gobject-1-0 liblircclient0 libllvm3.1 liblouis2 liblouis-data libltdl7 liblua5.1-0 liblvm2app2.2 libmailtools-perl libmeanwhile1 libmessaging-menu0 libmetacity-private0a libmhash2 libminiupnpc8 libmission-control-plugins0 libmng1 libmtdev1 libmtp9 libmtp-common libmtp-runtime libmusicbrainz5-0 libmx-1.0-2 libmx-bin libmx-common libmythes-1.2-0 libnatpmp1 libnautilus-extension1a libneon27-gnutls libnet-dns-perl libnet-domain-tld-perl libnetfilter-conntrack3 libnet-ip-perl libnettle4 libnice10 libnl-route-3-200 libnm-glib4 libnm-glib-vpn1 libnm-gtk0 libnm-gtk-common libnm-util2 libnotify4 libnotify-bin libnspr4 libnss3-1d libnss3 libnss-mdns libnux-3.0-0 libnux-3.0-common liboauth0 libogg0 libopencc1 libopenobex1 liborc-0.4-0 libpackagekit-glib2-14 libpam-cap libpam-freerdp libpam-gnome-keyring libpam-xdg-support libpango1.0-0 libpangomm-1.4-1 libpango-perl libpaper1 libpaper-utils libpeas-1.0-0 libpeas-common libperl5.14 libpixman-1-0 libplist1 libpoppler28 libpoppler-glib8 libportaudio2 libprotobuf7 libprotoc7 libproxy1 libproxy1-plugin-gsettings libproxy1-plugin-networkmanager libpth20 libpulse0 libpulsedsp libpulse-mainloop-glib0 libpurple0 libpurple-bin libpwquality1 libpython3.2 libqjson0 libqpdf8 libqt4-dbus libqt4-declarative libqt4-designer libqt4-help libqt4-network libqt4-script libqt4-scripttools libqt4-sql libqt4-sql-sqlite libqt4-svg libqt4-test libqt4-xml libqt4-xmlpatterns libqtassistantclient4 libqtcore4 libqtgui4 libqtwebkit4 libquvi7 libquvi-scripts libraptor2-0 librasqal3 libraw1394-11 libraw5 librdf0 libreoffice-base-core libreoffice-calc libreoffice-common libreoffice-core libreoffice-draw libreoffice-emailmerge libreoffice-gnome libreoffice-gtk libreoffice-help-en-us libreoffice-impress libreoffice-math libreoffice-ogltrans libreoffice-pdfimport libreoffice-presentation-minimizer libreoffice-presenter-console libreoffice-style-human libreoffice-style-tango libreoffice-writer librest-0.7-0 librhythmbox-core6 librsvg2-2 librsvg2-common librsync1 libsamplerate0 libsane-common libsane-hpaio libsane libsecret-1-0 libsecret-common libsensors4 libsgutils2-2 libshout3 libsignon-extension1 libsignon-glib1 libsignon-plugins-common1 libsignon-qt1 libsm6 libsmbclient libsndfile1 libsnmp15 libsnmp-base libsocket6-perl libsonic0 libsoup2.4-1 libsoup-gnome2.4-1 libspectre1 libspeechd2 libspeex1 libspeexdsp1 libssh-4 libstartup-notification0 libstlport4.6ldbl libsyncdaemon-1.0-1 libsync-menu1 libsysfs2 libt1-5 libtag1c2a libtag1-vanilla libtalloc2 libtdb1 libtelepathy-farstream2 libtelepathy-glib0 libtelepathy-logger2 libthai0 libthai-data libtheora0 libtiff5 libtimezonemap1 libtotem0 libtotem-plparser17 libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0 libubuntuoneui-3.0-1 libudisks2-0 libufe-xidgetter0 libunistring0 libupower-glib1 liburi-perl libusbmuxd2 libutempter0 libuuid-perl libv4l-0 libv4lconvert0 libvisual-0.4-0 libvisual-0.4-plugins libvncserver0 libvorbis0a libvorbisenc2 libvorbisfile3 libvte-2.90-9 libvte-2.90-common libwacom2 libwacom-common libwavpack1 libwbclient0 libwebkitgtk-3.0-0 libwebkitgtk-3.0-common libwmf0.2-7-gtk libwmf0.2-7 libwnck22 libwnck-3-0 libwnck-3-common libwnck-common libwpd-0.9-9 libwpg-0.2-2 libwps-0.2-2 libx11-xcb1 libx86-1 libxatracker1 libxaw7 libxcb-dri2-0 libxcb-glx0 libxcb-render0 libxcb-shape0 libxcb-shm0 libxcb-util0 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxfixes3 libxfont1 libxft2 libxi6 libxinerama1 libxkbfile1 libxklavier16 libxmu6 libxp6 libxpm4 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxres1 libxslt1.1 libxt6 libxtst6 libxv1 libxvmc1 libxxf86dga1 libxxf86vm1 libyajl2 libyaml-tiny-perl libyelp0 libzeitgeist-1.0-1 libzephyr4 \
  lightdm \
  lightdm-remote-session-freerdp \
  light-themes \
  lintian \
  linux-headers-generic-pae \
  linux-sound-base \
  lvm2 \
  mcp-account-manager-uoa \
  media-player-info \
  metacity-common \
  mobile-broadband-provider-info \
  modemmanager \
  mousetweaks \
  mscompress \
  mtools \
  nautilus-data \
  nautilus \
  nautilus-sendto-empathy \
  nautilus-sendto \
  nautilus-share \
  network-manager-gnome \
  network-manager \
  network-manager-pptp-gnome \
  network-manager-pptp \
  notify-osd-icons \
  notify-osd \
  nux-tools \
  obex-data-server \
  obexd-client \
  onboard \
  oneconf \
  openprinting-ppds \
  overlay-scrollbar-gtk2 \
  overlay-scrollbar-gtk3 \
  overlay-scrollbar \
  patchutils \
  pcmciautils \
  pkg-config \
  plymouth-label \
  plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo \
  pm-utils \
  policykit-1-gnome \
  policykit-desktop-privileges \
  poppler-data \
  poppler-utils \
  pptp-linux \
  printer-driver-c2esp \
  printer-driver-foo2zjs \
  printer-driver-gutenprint \
  printer-driver-hpcups \
  printer-driver-hpijs \
  printer-driver-min12xxw \
  printer-driver-pnm2ppa \
  printer-driver-postscript-hp \
  printer-driver-ptouch \
  printer-driver-pxljr \
  printer-driver-sag-gdi \
  printer-driver-splix \
  protobuf-compiler \
  pulseaudio \
  pulseaudio-module-bluetooth \
  pulseaudio-module-gconf \
  pulseaudio-module-x11 \
  pulseaudio-utils \
  python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets \
  python3-aptdaemon \
  python3-aptdaemon.pkcompat \
  python3-brlapi \
  python3-cairo \
  python3-crypto \
  python3-defer \
  python3-gi-cairo \
  python3-httplib2 \
  python3-louis \
  python3-lxml \
  python3-oauthlib \
  python3-pkg-resources \
  python3-pyatspi2 \
  python3-pycurl \
  python3-software-properties \
  python3-speechd \
  python3-virtkey \
  python3-xkit \
  python-appindicator \
  python-apport \
  python-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets \
  python-aptdaemon \
  python-cairo \
  python-configglue \
  python-cupshelpers \
  python-cups \
  python-dbus-dev \
  python-dbus \
  python-debtagshw \
  python-defer \
  python-dirspec \
  python-gconf \
  python-gi-cairo \
  python-gi \
  python-gnomekeyring \
  python-gobject-2 \
  python-gobject \
  python-gst0.10 \
  python-gtk2 \
  python-httplib2 \
  python-ibus \
  python-imaging \
  python-libxml2 \
  python-lxml \
  python-mako \
  python-markupsafe \
  python-notify \
  python-oauth \
  python-pexpect \
  python-piston-mini-client \
  python-problem-report \
  python-protobuf \
  python-pycurl \
  python-pyinotify \
  python-qt4-dbus \
  python-qt4 \
  python-renderpm \
  python-reportlab-accel \
  python-reportlab \
  python-simplejson \
  python-sip \
  python-smbc \
  python-twisted-names \
  python-twisted-web \
  python-ubuntuone-client \
  python-ubuntuone-control-panel \
  python-ubuntuone-storageprotocol \
  python-ubuntu-sso-client \
  python-uno \
  python-xdg \
  python-zeitgeist \
  qdbus \
  qpdf \
  qt-at-spi \
  radeontool \
  remmina-common \
  remmina \
  remmina-plugin-rdp \
  remmina-plugin-vnc \
  remote-login-service \
  rfkill \
  rhythmbox-data \
  rhythmbox \
  rhythmbox-mozilla \
  rhythmbox-plugin-cdrecorder \
  rhythmbox-plugin-magnatune \
  rhythmbox-plugins \
  rhythmbox-plugin-zeitgeist \
  rhythmbox-ubuntuone \
  rtkit \
  samba-common-bin \
  samba-common \
  sane-utils \
  seahorse \
  sessioninstaller \
  session-migration \
  shared-mime-info \
  shotwell \
  signond \
  signon-keyring-extension \
  signon-plugin-oauth2 \
  signon-plugin-password \
  signon-ui \
  simple-scan \
  smbclient \
  sni-qt \
  software-center-aptdaemon-plugins \
  software-center \
  software-properties-common \
  software-properties-gtk \
  sound-theme-freedesktop \
  speech-dispatcher \
  ssh-askpass-gnome \
  ssl-cert \
  syslinux-common \
  syslinux \
  syslinux-legacy \
  system-config-printer-common \
  system-config-printer-gnome \
  system-config-printer-udev \
  telepathy-gabble \
  telepathy-haze \
  telepathy-idle \
  telepathy-indicator \
  telepathy-logger \
  telepathy-mission-control-5 \
  telepathy-salut \
  thin-client-config-agent \
  thunderbird-gnome-support \
  thunderbird \
  toshset \
  totem-common \
  totem \
  totem-mozilla \
  totem-plugins \
  transmission-common \
  transmission-gtk \
  ttf-dejavu-core \
  ttf-indic-fonts-core \
  ttf-punjabi-fonts \
  ttf-ubuntu-font-family \
  ttf-wqy-microhei \
  ubuntu-artwork \
  ubuntu-docs \
  ubuntu-drivers-common \
  ubuntu-extras-keyring \
  ubuntu-mono \
  ubuntuone-client-gnome \
  ubuntuone-client \
  ubuntuone-control-panel \
  ubuntuone-control-panel-qt \
  ubuntuone-couch \
  ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk \
  ubuntu-settings \
  ubuntu-sounds \
  ubuntu-sso-client \
  ubuntu-sso-client-qt \
  ubuntu-system-service \
  ubuntu-wallpapers \
  ubuntu-wallpapers-quantal \
  udisks2 \
  udisks \
  unattended-upgrades \
  uno-libs3 \
  unzip \
  update-inetd \
  update-manager \
  update-notifier \
  upower \
  ure \
  usb-creator-common \
  usb-creator-gtk \
  usb-modeswitch-data \
  usb-modeswitch \
  usbmuxd \
  vbetool \
  vino \
  wamerican \
  watershed \
  wodim \
  x11-apps \
  x11-common \
  x11-session-utils \
  x11-utils \
  x11-xfs-utils \
  x11-xkb-utils \
  x11-xserver-utils \
  xbitmaps \
  xcursor-themes \
  xdg-user-dirs-gtk \
  xdg-user-dirs \
  xdg-utils \
  xdiagnose \
  xfonts-base \
  xfonts-encodings \
  xfonts-mathml \
  xfonts-scalable \
  xfonts-utils \
  xinit \
  xinput \
  xorg-docs-core \
  xorg \
  xserver-common \
  xserver-xorg-core \
  xserver-xorg-input-all \
  xserver-xorg-input-evdev \
  xserver-xorg-input-mouse \
  xserver-xorg-input-synaptics \
  xserver-xorg-input-vmmouse \
  xserver-xorg-input-wacom \
  xserver-xorg \
  xserver-xorg-video-all \
  xserver-xorg-video-ati \
  xserver-xorg-video-cirrus \
  xserver-xorg-video-fbdev \
  xserver-xorg-video-intel \
  xserver-xorg-video-mach64 \
  xserver-xorg-video-mga \
  xserver-xorg-video-modesetting \
  xserver-xorg-video-neomagic \
  xserver-xorg-video-nouveau \
  xserver-xorg-video-openchrome \
  xserver-xorg-video-qxl \
  xserver-xorg-video-r128 \
  xserver-xorg-video-radeon \
  xserver-xorg-video-s3 \
  xserver-xorg-video-savage \
  xserver-xorg-video-siliconmotion \
  xserver-xorg-video-sis \
  xserver-xorg-video-sisusb \
  xserver-xorg-video-tdfx \
  xserver-xorg-video-trident \
  xserver-xorg-video-vesa \
  xserver-xorg-video-vmware \
  xterm \
  xul-ext-ubufox \
  xul-ext-websites-integration \
  yelp \
  yelp-xsl \
  zeitgeist-core \
  zeitgeist-datahub \
  zeitgeist \
  zenity-common \
  zenity \
  zip
  ```

---

You might want to consider install [Ubuntu server edition](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/server) instead. It's a minimal installation, so you can install the packages you need, rather than remove the ones you don't.

Comment: We have a question for how to remove Unity already, what we're missing is one on how to remove GNOME. See: http://askubuntu.com/questions/6302/how-can-you-remove-unity

Comment: That's quite a vague question. Assuming that you're starting from a Ubuntu 12.10 desktop install, what do you consider GNOME? Surely, the second list of packages in my answer would include GNOME?

Comment: Unity relies on GNOME so @Flimm is right.

Comment: Please mention to put it into a shell script. (100 years later, "Just up to zenity")

Comment: `samba` depends on `update-inetd`, so don't remove it if you want to access windows networks.

Answer (score 3):

Also consider using a different Ubuntu [flavour](https://askubuntu.com/questions/690/what-is-the-difference-between-ubuntu-and-its-derivatives) if you want a minimal installation.  Both server edition and Lubuntu would be suitable.  Obviously Lubuntu would be best if you want some sort of X capability and it will have no trouble running on that amount of RAM.

Comment: I think this is the way to go. Install Ubuntu server and it'll be as bare-bones as possible. http://www.ubuntu.com/download/server
At this point, if you want graphics, install a simpler WM, like xfce or something.

Comment: Just get the mini.iso, they do still do that, don't they? Sorry, not caught up.

Comment: @acematrix : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD .