# Installed KDE on 12.04, how do I remove Gnome?

Tags: 12.04, unity, gnome, uninstall

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove GNOME completely?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/209746/how-to-remove-gnome-completely)

After following [this guide](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/switch-gnome-kde-45-ubuntu-1004/) to install KDE and trying it out for a while, I want to remove Gnome (Unity, not 3--I'm not sure if the distinction is majorly important or not). The problem is that the 'remove Gnome' command linked is actually the remove KDE command--and I can't find a way to remove Gnome.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove ubuntu software center using synaptic package manager?

else

from terminal :

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove ubuntu-desktop
```

Comment: That doesn't appear to be installed in the first place, which makes removing it hard (the package is marked as not installed, though Unity is).

Answer (score 0):

you can try this :

sudo apt-get remove unity unity-2d-places unity-2d unity-2d-panel unity-2d-spread unity-asset-pool unity-services unity-lens-files unity-lens-music unity-lens-applications gir1.2-unity-4.0 unity-common indicator-sound indicator-power indicator-appmenu libindicator6 indicator-application evolution-indicator indicator-datetime indicator-messages libnux-1.0-0 nuxtools

Comment: 'Virtual packages like 'gir1.2-unity-4.0' can't be removed
E: Unable to locate package libindicator6
E: Unable to locate package libnux-1.0-0
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libnux-1.0-0'
E: Unable to locate package nuxtools'

Comment: this means nuxtools package is not present ... so whatever is not present delete that part of command ie run :sudo apt-get remove unity unity-2d-places unity-2d unity-2d-panel unity-2d-spread unity-asset-pool unity-services unity-lens-files unity-lens-music unity-lens-applications unity-common indicator-sound indicator-power indicator-appmenu indicator-application evolution-indicator indicator-datetime indicator-messages

Comment: Ah, that worked. Does it remove the entirety of the default ubuntu desktop environment, or is there more to it than that? The amount of space taken up by adding KDE was certainly much larger.