# How to turn Ubuntu into LXDE without a fresh system instruction?

Tags: 13.10, lubuntu, system-installation, software-installation, lxde

I would like to know how to convert Ubuntu into Lubuntu, without a fresh installation of the system.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can install lubuntu-desktop, which is the desktop environment lxde plus the applications that make up the lubuntu distribution by typing in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop
```

Reboot for effect. All your files should still be there;)

I wouldn't bother removing Gnome completely unless you are very low on disk space.

It's also possible to install Lubuntu-desktop from the ubuntu software center.

Comment: I am already using lxde but I want to replace the whole ubuntu system for full lubuntu not just the desktop environment, If I used burned flash or cd then I could lose hundreds of giga bites of my documents, is there any way to do that ? without partitions and just as if you are deleting a system for another system

Comment: installing the lubuntu-desktop package will install all the applications that come with Lubuntu. So it's not just lxde.

Answer (score 2):

You can unistall current unity desktop environment and install LXDE desktop environment.

[How to remove GNOME completely?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/209746/how-to-remove-gnome-completely) will help you to remove your current desktop environment.

Then type as follow to install lxde:
sudo apt-get install lxde

This will give you desktop environment similar to that of lubuntu.

for more information, see http://wiki.lxde.org/en/Ubuntu

Comment: I am already using lxde but I want to replace the whole ubuntu system for full lubuntu not just the desktop environment, If I used burned flash or cd then I could lose hundreds of giga bites of my documents, is there any way to do that ? without partitions and just as if you are deleting a system for another system.

Answer (score 1):

I removed Gnome completely from TTY by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> using

```
sudo apt-get purge gdm
```

Then installed Unity and installed Lubuntu and here it is full Lubuntu.

Thank you Monis