# Clean install of Xubuntu over Ubuntu: will GRUB continue to work?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, xubuntu, boot-repair

I installed Ubuntu 13.10 a few days ago, and had to use boot-repair to get dual boot (with Windows 8.1 on a computer with UEFI) working properly, setting up GRUB and all that. But I kind of don't like Unity, and would like to use Xfce instead. I'm debating being lazy and just using xubuntu-desktop versus doing a fresh install of Xubuntu, but in the event that I do a fresh install, would I have to run boot-repair once more or would GRUB and the booting process remain intact and be able to boot Xubuntu immediately?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you will likely have to run boot repair again to be able to boot into windows.

Installing the xbutnutu-destop package is a better option if you want to avoid this.

Once you are satisfied that you don't ever want to run gnome or unity again you can remove them per [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/209746/how-to-remove-gnome-completely), but be careful not to remove X.