# Ubuntu 16.04 is lagging, fan is running very fast and over- heating after I changed my grub file to nomodeset!! (No dual-Boot)

Tags: boot, 16.04, fan, overheating

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS last week.
First, it was booting to a black screen so I set the grub file to **nomodeset**.
After doing this, my videos and system started lagging, sometimes more sometimes less.

I have performed following steps to improve lagging:

1. set **GRUB_TIMEOUT = 0**,  but that didn't help me.
2. set temp_throttle to 80, that also didn't improved performance.
3. Used `sudo gedit /etc/sysctl.conf` and  added one line to file `vm.swappiness = 15` (According to one answer).

**Is it something because of video drivers since I've processor AMD A4-3330MX APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics × 2**

**If my processor is too old to handle Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, then kindly suggest me the version which can run on this processor.**

Laptop Specs: 
[Laptop Specifications](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYPPE.png)

Output from `top` in terminal: 
[Output from top command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jhp8.png)

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/517413/how-do-ubuntu-flavors-compare-regarding-resource-consumption-and-performance which is four years old plus  https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=ubuntu-1704-desks&num=1 and https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=ubu-1704-desktops&num=1 which are nearly two years old but those should provide some idea.

Comment: what's the ram size??

Comment: RAM is of 6 GB.