# Dual pentium m install

Tags: cpuinfo

I have recently acquired a number of embedded touch screen computers to tinker with. One of them has two CPUs in one machine. I have managed to install and run various versions of Ubuntu and other operating systems; however, none seem to be able to see both CPUs in my installed machine. How do I allow my operating system to see both CPUs? I should note the system has 2 sockets Pentium m 1.4 and I have tried ubuntu mate 32 bit , lubuntu 32 bit, ubuntu and bodhi linux legacy

Comment: What do you mean by " none seem to be able to see both CPU"

Comment: First, how many cores does each one have? Multiply that by 2. Next, run EITHER `snap install htop` or `sudo apt install htop`. Do NOT do both. Now, run `htop`. How many cores shows up in the top left? Both should show up. If they do not, one of your processors may be configured incorrectly in the BIOS or just may not show up at all. Good luck!

Comment: Pentium m only have single cor however this board has 2 separate CPU both Pentium m single core, I'll ty htop tonight when I get home thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do Ubuntu flavors compare regarding resource consumption and performance?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/517413/how-do-ubuntu-flavors-compare-regarding-resource-consumption-and-performance)