# Ubuntu on HP TX2500 (or Xubuntu, Lubuntu, etc.)

Tags: xubuntu, lubuntu, hp, wacom

I am fairly new to Ubuntu and would like to run Ubuntu on my HP TX2500. Or Xubuntu if that would make it work more smooth. Or even Lubuntu.
But I can't find any guides about installing some recent version of Ubuntu to my system.
This are the specifications of my system:
http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?cc=nl&lc=nl&dlc=nl&docname=c01470267
Except the following differences:
 - AMD X2 ZM-86 (2.4GHz)
 - 4GB memory

I did find this guide about installing 8.04 to this system:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=873188

And this one about 9.10:

[[I can't post more than 2 links..]]

And some people on this site about the TX2500:

[[I can't post more than 2 links..]]

[[I can't post more than 2 links..]]

What should I install? Ubuntu, Xubuntu or Lubuntu? Or even something else?
I mainly use it for browsing and viewing movies and streams. (But I can use windows for those movies/streams if that is an better platform)
And which parts of the 8.04 guide is still usable and what part needs to change?

Comment: See [How do I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/q/6328/22949) and [What is the difference between Ubuntu and its derivatives?](http://askubuntu.com/q/690/22949) For the most part, installation works about the same on different makes and models of computer.

Answer (score 0):

The main differences between the different *buntu systems is the Desktop Environment (DE) that they use. A lot of the choices boil down to personal preference as there are no major structural differences beneath the hood. They will all run the same software. Ubuntu running Unity is the heaviest on system resources, but it is probably the most polished GUI, Xubuntu runs XFCE and is very fast and quite customizable. Lubuntu is the lightest and fastest of all of the *buntus. It isn't as easy to customize but works very well on older machines and netbooks. I personally use Lubuntu on my i3 based laptop because I love how fast and lightweight it is. Another bonus to a lightweight system is increased battery life.

I would recommend getting a liveCD of each of them and just try them out. This will give you a good idea if drivers are working. In a live session you can't do much harm (just don't go messing with Gparted). When you are downloading make sure you select the right iso for your architecture.

Comment: "*Ubuntu running Unity is the heaviest on system resources*" Are you sure Unity consumes more resources than [GNOME 3](http://www.gnome.org/) with [GNOME Shell](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShell) (as provided in [Ubuntu GNOME](http://ubuntugnome.org/)) or [KDE 4 Plasma Workspaces](https://www.kde.org/) (as provided in [Kubuntu](http://www.kubuntu.org/))? I'm not saying this is not the case, but it's not obvious (at least to me) that this would be the case. So if you know it is, you might want to add a link or further explanation to your answer.

Comment: I purposely didn't mention Gnome as it wasn't mentioned by the OP. I was purely comparing the standard out of box Ubuntu Xubuntu and Lubuntu as they were what were originally the options given. To be honest, I'm not sure whether Gnome or Unity would run heavier. But as I also mentioned, it is mostly user preference which system to go with

Comment: Oke thanks, I'm installing Ubuntu 14.04 right now. LiveCD started and seemed to work. Didn't need to use acpi=off as in the 8.04.1 guide.
But is it also possible to try Xubuntu and Lubuntu in the same Ubuntu installation? Because the difference is Unity, Xfce and LXDE right?
Or do I need to uninstall one before I can try another?

Comment: You can install more than one Desktop Environment within the same installation and choose between them at your login screen. Run 'sudo apt-get install xfce4' for XFCE or 'sudo apt-get install lxde' for LXDE desktop

Comment: I added Xfce and LXDE and I found I should delete some programs because it could't have an negative influence (when you install XFCE over Ubuntu)

Comment: sudo apt-get remove nautilus gnome-power-manager gnome-screensaver gnome-termina* gnome-pane* gnome-applet* gnome-bluetooth gnome-desktop* gnome-sessio* gnome-user* gnome-shell-common compiz compiz* unity unity* hud zeitgeist zeitgeist* python-zeitgeist libzeitgeist* activity-log-manager-common gnome-control-center gnome-screenshot overlay-scrollba* && sudo apt-get install xubuntu-community-wallpapers && sudo apt-get autoremove

Comment: But first thing: the layout of FXCE isn't the same as I saw on an Xubuntu LiveCD. Is this a settings or theme configuration.

And second, I think I shouldn't had installed both XFCE and LXDE because I am getting graphics errors now. Is there an way to undo my actions? Or am I forced to do a clean install again?

Comment: What you have installed is not Xubuntu, it is the xfce desktop environment within ubuntu, so it would not look exactly the same. If you want to remove them go to terminal and type 'sudo apt-get remove xfce4' for xfce and 'sudo apt-get remove lxde' for lxde.

Comment: Another way of going about it is to install ubuntu, xubuntu and lubuntu separately by dual booting. This would take up a lot more space on your hard drive however, because you are essentially installing 3 separate os's rather than just 1 using 3 different desktop environments:

http://www.linux.com/learn/answers/view/1346-how-can-i-dual-boot-two-or-more-linux-distros