# Compaq Presario SR1123WM, HELP?

Tags: badblocks

1GB memory, 90% free 70GB HDD 7200rpm, Intel Celeron (P) 330 2.66 GHz 533 FSB

installed Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS 32 bit. It is slower than prior Windows XP 32bit OS.

what is wrong? may I improve performance?

Comment: Also, you have a Windows XP machine and are running the latest and greatest Ubuntu...  Have a look here as well: [Which flavour of Ubuntu to choose](http://askubuntu.com/questions/690/what-is-the-difference-between-ubuntu-and-its-derivatives)

Answer (score 1):

I would start by adding physical memory; you need at least 2GB to run Ubuntu. Or, you could try one of the lightweight versions, like Lubuntu or Xubuntu, both of which use less system resources.