# What the difference between performance the of Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and Windows 10?

Tags: performance, windows-10

I want to know the difference between performance of Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with Windows 10. Features like RAM, interact with hardware, CPU usage, shutdown delay... etc.

Comment: An advice: The app database is very limited.

Comment: @Raphael what are you talking about? ubuntu has the largest app database of any other linux distro and any other non debian based linux distro by more than 2x the number of apps compared to the closest next https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Linux_distributions#Package_management_and_installation

Comment: suse is the only one that even comes close at 24,094 compared to the 56,705 available packages from the ubuntu repos

Comment: @mchid The app database in comparison to Windows.

Comment: I think you mean to say that the windows app database is quite limited?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, most Linux systems are known for their excellent hardware support: most modules (a.k.a. "drivers") are already installed by default while others can be installed easily.

Ubuntu is running smoothly without problems and is built to be very user friendly.

Performance wise: Overall it's as good as Windows and better most of the time on the same hardware depending on your [choice of flavour](https://askubuntu.com/questions/690/what-is-the-difference-between-ubuntu-and-its-derivatives).