# Pixilated display, clicks not working on Toshiba Satellite

Tags: command-line

I have an old toshiba satellite (A135-S2326) laptop I downloaded Ubuntu 14.04.03 and then booted it through a Usb. The problem is if it decides to actually boot and I get passed the log in screen. What happens is my screen is heavily pixelated and their is a system error. I can move my mouse but anytime I try to click something, nothing happens. So the only thing I can do is go to the terminal. The problem with the terminal is I'm not connected to my wi-if and I don't know how to, so I think that's why it's also not allowing me to install any package. If I type "Sudo apt-get install " it will say already installed and below that line will say could not find package. I've been trying to fix this and research this for the last 5 hours. I'm at the verge of breaking my laptop, this is my last resort so please help.....I'm new to this btw(if you can't tell)

Answer (score 1):

I have a Toshiba Satellite A105-S4004 and it runs Lubuntu 14.04 just fine.  Ubuntu 14.04 may be too much for that old of a system (I used to run 12.04 2D Desktop on it and that was OK, but 3D desktop was problematic.) Try Lubuntu or Xubuntu.

Comment: What's the difference?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/690/what-is-the-difference-between-ubuntu-and-its-derivatives