# Are all the softwares which are there for Ubuntu available on Kubuntu?

Tags: kubuntu, software-center, kde

I want to install a lighter flavor of `Ubuntu`, say `KDE`. But I am worried about the softwares and other packages will work or not on that flavor and also that it can be installed with the most convenient way of installing softwares which is `apt-get` command. I generally use `ubuntu` to build `AOSP ROMS` and therefore I don't want an `OS` which is "resource hungry" like the `Unity-Desktop-Environment`. Generally what I want are these softwares to be installed and work flawlessly:

```
git-core gnupg flex bison gperf build-essential \
  zip curl zlib1g-dev gcc-multilib g++-multilib libc6-dev-i386 \
  lib32ncurses5-dev x11proto-core-dev libx11-dev lib32z-dev ccache \
  libgl1-mesa-dev libxml2-utils xsltproc unzip
```

Comment: KDE is not lighter than Ubuntu.

Comment: Really??But I read somewhere (perhaps quora) that KDE should be used in a computer having low resources like 2gb ram, etc.. Do that do not mean that it is lighter than Ubuntu??

Comment: Well, then should I go for Lubuntu then??

Comment: That's a personal opinion ;-)  Oh I just found this: https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/5l39tz/linux_distros_ram_consumption_comparison_updated/ The RAM shown there is not just the DE. I use Budgie myself but have RAM to spare ;-)

Comment: and here a bare footprint (so with nothing running): https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/3j7i0t/is_kde_really_as_resource_heavy_as_everyone_says/

Comment: Xubuntu and Lubuntu would be my first choices for a lighter Ubuntu-based DE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main differences between Ubuntu and Kubuntu are the default installed packages, sponsors and the environments, which means any package that can be installed in Ubuntu it can also be installed in Kubuntu. And yes, Kubuntu and all other ubuntu like ditros use `apt` as their packaged manager since there all Debian derivatives.

For More details see [What is the difference between Ubuntu and its derivatives?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/690/what-is-the-difference-between-ubuntu-and-its-derivatives) And https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MetaPackages