# Which Ubuntu flavour is best for my device?

Tags: system-installation

Processor

- Model: Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-2350M
- Speed:‌ 2300 MHz
- Architecture in use:‌ 64-bit
- Architecture(s) supported:‌ 32-bit, 64-bit

Components‌

- RAM: 4.0 GB (3.7 GiB)
- ‌Graphics: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller

I am totally new to Linux OS. Please recommend me the most stable and easy to use flavor of Ubuntu. And also should I use an LTS release or STS release version and 32bit or 64bit ? Thanks in advance = )

Comment: It is free. So why not try out what works for you.  The desktop might not be your taste even though it might suit your system.

Comment: Related: [What is the difference between Ubuntu and its derivatives?](https://askubuntu.com/q/690/301745)

Comment: Related: [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](https://askubuntu.com/q/206407/301745)

Comment: Related: [What are the system requirements for each flavour of Ubuntu Desktop](https://askubuntu.com/q/333795/301745)

Comment: FWIW, my laptop has pretty similar specs and can run any flavour of Ubuntu.

Comment: “Try it out” really is the best tip one can give – read about the different flavours (see my comment below), then download your favourites and create live usb sticks from them, this way you can just try them out from usb. This will not be as fast as a normal installation, but it's enough to get a picture. Then just install the one you like most. Switching btw is really not hard.

Answer (score 4):

Since your processor supports 64 bit, use 64 bit.  64 bit will let you upgrade your memory at a later time if you find 4GB to be too little.

I recommend that new users to Ubuntu use the latest LTS which would be 16.04 LTS. That way you will have a stable system for a number of years and a direct upgrade path to the next LTS when it is released in April 2018.

Comment: [This article](https://www.howtogeek.com/163154/linux-users-have-a-choice-8-linux-desktop-environments/) gives you a good overview over the main existing desktop environments. With 4 GB of RAM you don't have to use a lightweight one like LXDE (Lubuntu) or Xfce (Xubuntu), but you still may – I'm only using Lubuntu even on up-to-date hardware, because I find it just the best for my needs.