# Vega runtime error on linux mint

Tags: java

I installed vega from [Here](https://subgraph.com/vega/download/) but when I was trying to open it its gives me following error

```
vega ./Vega
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 
warning: Ignoring option PermSize; support was removed in 8.0 OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 
warning: Ignoring option MaxPermSize; support was removed in 8.0 
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred 
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage 
(file:/home/an2/vega/plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.8.0.v20120529-1548.jar)
     to method java.net.URLClassLoader.addURL(java.net.URL) 
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of 
org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage 
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of 
further illegal reflective access operations 
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

Here is my java version

```
java -version 
openjdk version "11.0.2" 2019-01-15 OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.2+9-Ubuntu-3ubuntu118.04.3) 
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.2+9-Ubuntu-3ubuntu118.04.3, mixed mode, sharing)
```

How can I solved this error and run vega?

Comment: I don't see an error. All I see are warnings and an advice. "WARNING: Please
    > consider reporting this to the maintainers of     org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage". Please follow up on that. If vega does not run it should not be due to these messages.

Comment: Have you tried installing there posted requirement: `sudo apt-get install libwebkitgtk-1.0` (taken from the linked site)

Comment: I already do that @tannerli

Comment: What version of Java are you running? You can probably find out by executing `ls -l /etc/alternatives/java` If it's a version 11, it might be helpful to explicitly install `openjdk-8-jre` and try with that one

Comment: After running `ls -l /etc/alternatives/java` it's returning this `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 43 Jul 11  2018 /etc/alternatives/java -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java`

Comment: Linux Mint is Ubuntu-based, but not [an official Ubuntu flavour](https://askubuntu.com/questions/690/what-is-the-difference-between-ubuntu-and-its-derivatives) thus off-topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause is for using **java-11-openjdk-amd64**

open terminal and run

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

and choose **java-8-openjdk-amd64**

and run vega again.