# Best dstro for old 2011 laptop running Windows 7

Tags: 20.04

I have an old laptop with Pentium B950@2.10Ghz dual core processor with 3gb ram and 300gb HDD. It is running windows 7
and is running very slow. I usually need to do web browsing and attend zoom meetings.

I've never used linux before.

I'm thinking to go for Ubuntu (20.04LTS) and also upgrading the ram. Will it be helpful to me.

Comment: I'm using a 2009 dell & can tell you all run, however (esp. with 3gb of ram) I'd select which is best for you by what applications you will be using, so desktop libraries/toolkits don't differ to your wanted apps (rather than wasting RAM needing one set for your desktop, one for your apps). You've given too little detail as to which is best; but also your tastes as involved but I'd go for a *lighter* DE that matches your wanted/needed apps.

Comment: As for upgrading RAM - yep that is definitely worth it.  If ram is >5GB I tend to ignore the impacts of toolkit/libraries (this is rather technical, but applies to all OSes, in windows & macos they tend to only say you need more ram; I'm talking about why they document more ram) as it allows you to ignore the preparation/calculations required to keep your system efficient as you have more resources & wasteful behaviors aren't noticed as much...

Comment: Also see https://askubuntu.com/questions/690/what-is-the-difference-between-ubuntu-and-its-derivatives  (this is the question I wish I'd marked duplicate too; being a better one in my *opinion*)

Comment: Try Xubuntu and Lubuntu. They are lightweight compared to regular Ubuntu. Also check out [Antix](https://antixlinux.com/) and [MX Linux](https://mxlinux.org/) (XFCE edition). While not on topic on this site, they are Debian based, and work well with old computers.

Comment: [Ubuntu MATE](https://ubuntu-mate.org/) 20.04 LTS will allow you to get maximum usability from this hardware.